# Historical/Romance/Fantasy: Orphan Girl with Magic becomes ward of a mage

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to find a book that I probably read 15-25 yrs. ago. I have tried AbeBooks, Reddit, Goodreads and wrote to the New York Library (just did that today), Library of Congress (They acknowledged receipt about 10 days ago, but nothing further.), exchanged correspondence with the authors Jill Barnett and Lynn Kurland and I know it is not a Teresa Medeiros book.

I would describe it as Historical/Romance/Fantasy. It is definitely not set in modern times; possibly, Regency or Edwardian. A young orphan girl with nascent magical powers is sent by horse drawn carriage to become the ward of a mage/warlock/sorcerer/very advanced scientist (???). I think her grandfather sent her. I believe the destination was a great house, yet not a castle. I think there were 2 or 3 young boys near the girl's age who also lived there. I do not believe they were the adult man's sons, but possibly nephews. I remember comedic elements in the plots, but no danger. I think all of the children are gifted, but that the girl is the most powerful. As a grown adult, she and the male character fall in love and "live happily ever after".

Comment: I haven't found a matching story yet, but aspects of this reminds me of Mercedes Lackey's [Elemental Masters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elemental_Masters) books, which involve magic in Regency/Victorian times, and are often based off of a fairy tale.